# How to extract text from a several "div class" (html) using R?

Tags: html, css, r, regex, rvest

My goal is to extract info from this html page to create a database:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B0aGd85uKFDyOS1XTTc2QnNjRmc&usp=sharing

One of the variables is the price of the apartments. I've identified that some have the `div class="row_price"` code which includes the price (example A) but others don't have this code and therefore the price (example B). Hence I would like that R could read the observations without the price as `NA`, otherwise it will mixed the database by giving the price from the observation that follows.

## Example A

```
<div class="listing_column listing_row_price">
    <div class="row_price">
      $ 14,800
    </div>
<div class="row_info">Ayer&nbsp;19:53</div>
```

## Example B

```
<div class="listing_column listing_row_price">

<div class="row_info">Ayer&nbsp;19:50</div>
```

I think that if I extract the text from "listing_row_price" to the beginning of the "row_info" in a character vector I will be able to get my desired output, which is:

```
...
10 4000
11 14800
12 NA
13 14000
14 8000
...
```

But so far I've get this one and another full with `NA`.

```
...
10 4000
11 14800
12 14000
13 8000
14 8500
...
```

Commands used but didn't get what I want:

```
    html1<-read_html("file.html")
    title<-html_nodes(html1,"div")
    html1<-toString(title)
    pattern1<-'div class="row_price">([^<]*)<'
    title3<-unlist(str_extract_all(title,pattern1))
    title3<-title3[c(1:35)]
    pattern2<-'>\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t([^<*]*)'
    title3<-unlist(str_extract(title3,pattern2))
    title3<-gsub(">\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t $ ","",title3,fixed=TRUE)
    title3<-as.data.frame(as.numeric(gsub(",","", title3,fixed=TRUE)))
```

I also try with `pattern1<-'listing_row_price">([<div class="row_price">]?)([^<]*)<` that I think it says to extract the "listing_row_price" part, then if exist extract the "row_price" part, later get the digits and finally extract the `<` thats follows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, and depending on how consistent the HTML is, one may be better than another. A reasonably simple strategy that works in this case, though:

```
library(rvest)

page <- read_html('page.html')

# find all nodes with a class of "listing_row_price"
listings <- html_nodes(page, css = '.listing_row_price')

# for each listing, if it has two children get the text of the first, else return NA
prices <- sapply(listings, function(x){ifelse(length(html_children(x)) == 2, 
                                              html_text(html_children(x)[1]), 
                                              NA)})
# replace everything that's not a number with nothing, and turn it into an integer
prices <- as.integer(gsub('[^0-9]', '', prices))
```